# .war file already on tomcat9 webapps but inaccessible on website

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat9

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm just starting to learn web API using SPRING BOOT, Maven

To sum it up I already created a ".war" file and copied it to webapps folder of Tomcat9.
But I can't seem to access it, but the index.html is accessible.

**Here is supposed to be the .war file to be accessed**
[image]
**Here is my server's (Linux) file folder:**
[image]

**A screenshot of the accessible index.html under webapps/ROOT folder:**
[image]

I also tried putting my .war file inside webapps/ROOT/ folder but it is still not accessible also.

Sorry for the bad English, hoping for your kindest comments and guidance.

Comment: Have you considered alternative? How about creating JAR? Tomcat get embedded

Comment: @Popeye Yes I also created a .JAR , the same outcome

Comment: When you create JAR file, you do not deploy it with tomcat, Tomcat supposed to be embedded with your jar, you execute the jar file like a java application. `java -jar thefile.jar`

Comment: or even `./mvnw spring-boot:run` or  `mvn spring-boot:run` will trigger springboot to start tomcat

Comment: I tried your suggestion to use **java -jar thefile.jar**, but accessing it now returns a **Whitelabel Error Page**
**This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.**

Comment: I've figured it out now using .jar with the java -jar myfile.jar.
I ran this and proceed to browse it with my  @GetMapping route.
Thank you so much kind sir. Next thing to do is how to run .jar using PM2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it didn't start your application. Tomcat can deploy your application. however, it does not mean that your application has started/hosted, etc. To solve this problem, we need to see the Tomcat logs. There is definitely a detail in the logs. Another solution is, you might install the tomcat manager app and you will see if your application started or not there. If it seems to start there, definitely you have a network security problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input sir, this is one way to do it.
I've figured it out now using .jar with the java -jar myfile.jar.

instead of creating a .war file, I made a .jar file